# Minishift - Pod not started

Tags: java, deployment, openshift, grpc-java, minishift

I have problem with a java app on minishift. Build looks fine, but deploy failes.

I have following error:

```
Starting the Java application using /opt/jboss/container/java/run/run-java.sh ...
INFO exec  java -javaagent:/opt/jboss/container/jolokia/jolokia.jar=config=/opt/jboss/container/jolokia/etc/jolokia.properties -XX:+UseParallelOldGC -XX:MinHeapFreeRatio=10 -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=20 -XX:GCTimeRatio=4 -XX:AdaptiveSizePolicyWeight=90 -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=100m -XX:+ExitOnOutOfMemoryError -cp "." -jar /deployments/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar  
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: If the number of processors is expected to increase from one, then you should configure the number of parallel GC threads appropriately using -XX:ParallelGCThreads=N
no main manifest attribute, in /deployments/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your final image doesn't have a **META-INF/MANIFEST.MF**.

With your application, you should have a **pom.xml** like this one:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0</version>
      <configuration>
        <archive>
          <manifest>
            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
            <mainClass>com.mypackage.MyClass</mainClass>
          </manifest>
        </archive>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Openshift will create the `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` for you.